# Bluemix and Java Server Faces

Tags: java, jsf, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, websphere-liberty

I wonder if anyone have got java liberty profile in Bluemix to work with Java Server Faces. I have been a bit doubtful as one is supposed to code stateless in Cloud Foundry applications. But then I noticed the Session Cache Service, maybe that could help as it from the description seems able to hold sessions.
Has anyone tried this?

Best Regards

W

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluemix supports JSF 2.0 and 2.2 via Liberty runtime: https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/liberty/index.html#libertyfeatures
I have used it without any issue.

In parallel, if you want to persist HTTP Session, you can use the Session Cache service: https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/SessionCache/index.html
or other persistence system like Redis (also available in Bluemix catalog).